# Minecraft command block keeps adding text

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a command block work to spawn a structure.

I type in the command: `/structure load small_mine ~~1~`

It's set up to activate every 5000 ticks, but then when I check it again the command line looks like this: `/structure load small_mine ~~1~ /stru/stru`

Or something along those lines, like:

- [image: in-game screenshot of example of wrong command]
  `/structure load small_mine ~~1~small/stru/stru`
- [image: in-game screenshot of example of wrong command]
  `/structure load small_mine ~~1~/stru/stru/stru/stru`
- [image: in-game screenshot of example of wrong command]

  `/structure load small_mine ~~1~small/stru/stru/stru/stru/stru/stru/strusmallsmallloadsmall/stru`

Any tips or an answer of why? I'm on mobile, if that helps.

Comment: It has done this several times where it does this or adds other fragments of the command once it was that the next time it looked like that but also had "small" before the slashes It's almost like it's copy paste of fragments of the command

Comment: I have seen it do a lot of different one one time it was full to the text limit of repeated fragments of the initial command

Comment: I added a couple pictures to show what I meant about it.

Comment: Auto-complete (as in your mobile keyboard) maybe?